# clipping labels with z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, z-index

I have the vertical label "PINK" aligned in the middle of a section.
When I scroll down to the next section the "PINK" is being covered by the next section which is having an higher z-index.

```css
div.back1 {
    background-color: #FF00FF;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2000px;
    z-index: 10;
}
div.text1 {
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 20;
}
div.back2 {
    background-color: #0000FF;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2000px;
    z-index: 30;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="text1">PINK</div>
<div class="back1"></div>
<div class="back2"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to have a second title "BLUE" in the second section to appear as shown in the following mockup.

[image]

Is it possible to arrange the z-indexes to achieve this result? 
Is there another better way to clip the labels, keeping their alignment at 50% of the viewport?

Thanks a lot in advance for any contribution!

Comment: Interesting. I have absolutely no idea, but I'd love to know too.

Comment: why don't you just increase the z-index so its always on top and then use JS to change the wording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this code**

since you tagged jquery,i used it to add class `fixed`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.blue-text').hide();
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($('.blue').offset().top <= $('.pink-text').offset().top + 40)
{
  $('.blue-text').show();
  if($('.blue').offset().top <= $('.pink-text').offset().top){
     $('.blue-text').addClass('fixed');
  }
}
else{
  $('.blue-text').removeClass('fixed');
  $('.blue-text').hide();
}
});
});
```

```css
div.back1 {
    background-color: #FF00FF;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2000px;
    z-index: 10;
}
div.text1.fixed {
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 20;
}
div.back2 {
    background-color: #0000FF;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2000px;
    z-index: 30;
}
.blue,.pink {
    position: relative;
}
.text1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 31;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.text1.blue-text.fixed{
    z-index: 31;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color">
<div class="pink">
<div class="text1 pink-text fixed">PINK</div>
<div class="back1"></div>
</div>
<div class="blue">
<div class="text1 blue-text">BLUE</div>
<div class="back2"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the blue label scrolls with blue background though

Comment: @Amal the visual effect is that, although - quote KarlusdaWakoko - the blue label scrolls with blue background.